# Can I make an Opportunity Attack during Time Stop?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, opportunity-attack

Time Stop indicates that the caster has 1d4+1 rounds to do whatever they want and that time does not pass for other creatures. Presumably everyone is effectively barred from using their Reactions, but this is not expressly stated. Furthermore, it suggests that the caster could simply walk away from a character they are engaged in melee without using the Disengage action, but that is also not expressly stated by the spell.

Other spells and effects that remove Reactions specifically state as such. Such as Shocking Grasp:

> On a hit, the target takes 1d8 lightning damage, and it can’t take
>   reactions until the start of its next turn.

...Monk's Open Hand Technique:

> It can't take reactions until the end of your next turn.

...or the Gibbering Mouther's Gibbering ability:

> On a failure, the creature can’t take reactions until the start of its
>   next turn and rolls a d8 to determine what it does during its turn.

The exclusion of similar language within Time Stop is notable, so can the caster of Time Stop trigger Opportunity Attacks during the course of their Actions that others character may use Reactions to capitalize upon?

Comment: possibly related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152202/can-the-caster-of-time-stop-still-use-their-bonus-action-or-reaction

Answer (score 17):

### No the caster cannot trigger Opportunity Attacks while Time Stop is active

Time Stop includes the following two sentences:

> You briefly stop the flow of time for everyone but yourself. No time passes for other creatures while you take 1d4 + 1 turns in a row [...]

If time is stopped for all other creatures, they are unable to perceive and unable to act in any way.

A reaction is described as

> A reaction is an instant response to a trigger of some kind, which can occur on your turn or someone else's.

As you cannot perceive the trigger and cannot react (as no time is passing for you) you cannot take opportunity attacks against the caster.

Or to put it another way, the caster does not trigger Opportunity Attacks.

Comment: Nice call on the bit about not perceiving they've left.

Comment: I don't think this answer is wrong, but I think you're assuming aspects about time being stopped that make sense in the real world (for whatever value attempting to perceive time as stopped can have) and applying them to 5e. OA stipulate that, 'a creature that you can see moves out of your reach.' They don't stipulate what is perceived by the characters who are stopped, perhaps it just looks like the caster moves impossibly fast. As it is an OA, it can occur off-turn even if the opponent moves impossibly fast.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical D&D uses the plan English meaning of words. If they aren't defined in game then they take on the regular meaning of such words. The regular meaning of stopped time is literally a lack of an ability to perceive as nothing can get into your senses (due to time being stopped)